# MySQL Timestamp format

Tags: mysql, sql, date, timestamp, date-format

I have exported my database to a CSV file and the timestamp now liiks like this:

`1384204028`

How can I convert it to the typical format, for example `2013-01-19 03:14:07` ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use [`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1384204028);
```

or (equivalent but with parameter to control the format):

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1384204028, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
```

Answer (score 14):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to add a line in your DB-table, where you have a field as TIMESTAMP, you don't need to call a function. You just can pas a string, sql will do the rest.

```
INSERT INTO `DB_TABLE`(`id`, `message`, `next_time`) VALUES (12, 'hallo world', '20180601151343')
```

and will even work like this:

```
INSERT INTO `DB_TABLE`(`id`, `message`, `next_time`) VALUES (12, 'hallo world', '2018-06-01 15:13:43')
```